# What is the max number of Computer Engine VMs I can create?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is default the max number of Computer Engine VMs I can create? I need to create 1500 VMs in one project, is it possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should be asked of the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the following documentation, you will see that there are quotas on CPUs:

[Understanding quotas - CPU quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#cpu_quota)

There isn't quotas on Compute Engine instances per-se but instead quotas on the number of CPUs you can consume per project.

If you visit this page you will be take to the console for quotas:

[Cloud Console - IAM & Admin & Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas)

From there, filter on the word "cpu".

Next, pick a type of CPU and drill down in the details section.  You will then see the quotas by GCP region.  If you need more, pick a region and select "Edit Quotas" and make a request to up your quota limit.

Given your desire to have 1500 VMs in one project, what I would suggest is that you contact your local Google Cloud Platform representative.  1500 new VMs is likely worth chatting with your Google reps.  At a minimum, it is likely you won't be allocated 1500 VMs without some discussions on capacity planning.  Google will likely want to know what region(s) you want them in, how long they will be running, how many CPUs, etc. Google will also be able to advise on how to minimize your overall costs with notions like committed use discounts.